# How to update a method in a class in python?

Tags: python, class, methods, program-entry-point

I am trying to use python classes to define a series of methods.
This is the first time I use classes, and I am a newbie in python (and programming in general).
Specifically, I have a class which read a file containing the x, y and z coordinates of an object and calculate the min and max values for x, y and z. This class then call another class which create a dictionary {'x': ('mix_x', 'max_x')...}, interpolate all the possible min and max combination for x, y and z and return a box, containing the original object. This second class has three methods:

- creating the dictionary,
- interpolating the min and max to create a list of tuples (x, y, z), each tuples corresponding to the box vertices coordinates.
- given the vertices points, calculate each points of the box edges.

So far, the class work fine, but now I am trying to modify the box dimensions.
I created a new method inside the second class, which modify the min and max values in the dictionary so that if I apply the second and third method of the class to the new dictionary, it should create a new resized box.

The problem is that I don't know where to call the new method and how to make the other methods understand that they have to use the new dictionary for creating the new box.

This is how the code looks like now:

```
class Molecule:
def __init__(self, atoms):
    self.atoms = atoms
    self.extract_coords()
    self.find_min_max()

def extract_coords(self):
    self.coords = []
    a = []
    for line in self.atoms:
        x = float(line[30:38])
        y = float(line[38:46])
        z = float(line[46:54])
        a = [x, y, z]
        self.coords.append(a)

def find_min_max(self):
    self.min_max = {'min_x':min(x[0] for x in self.coords),
            'max_x':max(x[0] for x in self.coords),
            'min_y':min(y[1] for y in self.coords),
            'max_y':max(y[1] for y in self.coords),
            'min_z':min(z[2] for z in self.coords),
            'max_z':max(z[2] for z in self.coords)}
    self.bounding_box = BoundingBox(self.min_max)

class BoundingBox:
def __init__(self, min_max):
        self.min_max = min_max
        self.calc()
        self.calc_coords()
        self.calc_edges()

    def calc(self):
        self.bounding_box = {"x": (self.min_max['min_x'], self.min_max['max_x']),
                    "y": (self.min_max['min_y'], self.min_max['max_y']),
                    "z": (self.min_max['min_z'], self.min_max['max_z'])}

    def calc_coords(self):
        self.coords = []
        for x in self.bounding_box["x"]:
            for y in self.bounding_box["y"]:
                for z in self.bounding_box["z"]:
                    self.coords.append( [x,y,z] )

import sys
f = read_file(sys.argv[1])
atoms = extract_atoms(f)
mol = Molecule(atoms)
```

Now I am trying to use this new method:

```
def resize(self, value):
    for k,v in self.bounding_box.items():
     _min, _max = v
     size = (_max - _min) / (value) 
     _min = _min + (size/2) 
     _max = _max - (size/2) 
     self.bounding_box[k] = (_min, _max)
```

which should update self.bounding_box with the new min, max.
I am calling this method in this way:

```
import sys
f = read_file(sys.argv[1])
atoms = extract_atoms(f)
mol = Molecule(atoms)
mol.bounding_box.resize(3)
```

but the final box dimension are not updated.
What am I missing?
I apologize if I wasn't so clear. It is difficult for me to explain the problem as I never programmed before.
Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look too bad (you just messed up part of the indentation while posting). Maybe you could use `print` to check some values in `resize` (or use a full debugger).

Comment: Have you added a  `calc_coords()` after resizing, you possibly have reseized the box but not updated the coords.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I solved it now y adding calc_coords() to the method